# Count divs with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

Seems pretty simple but I can't get it to work.

I have two divs with the class 'user'. I want to output "you have 2 divs".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function divcount() {
            var mycount =  $('.user').length(); 
            document.write(mycount)
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple..

Comment: Wess, you can't write to the document after the DOM is complete using `document.write`. Try this instead: `$(document.body).append(mycount)` and then be sure to call your `divcount()` function somewhere to activate it.

Comment: should always use `console.log(String);` to debug :) works a lot better than `document.write`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Length](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length) is a property not a function. Size is a function.

Answer (score 10):

It’s either `$('.user').length` ([`length` property of *Array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)) or `$('.user').size()` ([`size` method of *jQuery*](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/size)).

Comment: I've tried both and I can't get it to output a digit in text. How would I do this?

Comment: Remove the divcount function.

Comment: @Wes: Do you ever call that `divcount` function?

Comment: I've changed it to this after some googling, but I'm still not getting an output. No errors or anything.


  $(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('.user').size(); 
  
   
  });

Comment: @Wes: `$(function(){ $(document.body).append( $('.user').length ); });` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's just `$('.user').length`.  It's a property, not a method call.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".user").length  // use the length property

$(".user").size()  // use the size method
```

notice that the code must be include in the $(function(){...}) block; like:

```
$(function(){
    alert( $(".user").length );
    alert( $(".user").size() );
});
```